# Not able to properly map c struct to c# struct

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm trying to map a bytearray in c#, which is of 56 bytes and the struct i got for it is like this in C

```
struct cequivalentstruct{
    uint32_t Descriptor;

    uint32_t Value;

    uint32_t Minimum;

    uint32_t Maximum;

    uint32_t Default;

    uint16_t Next;

    uint16_t Previous;

    char Units[4];

    uint16_t Multiplier;

    uint16_t Divisor;

    uint16_t Base;

    uint16_t Offset;

    char Link[3];

    char pad;

    char Name[16];
}
```

and i have coverted that to

```
         [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct ParameterResponse
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 4)]
            public uint Descriptor;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4, SizeConst = 4)]
            public uint Value;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 4)]
            public uint Minimum;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 4)]
            public uint Maximum;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 4)]
            public uint Default;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 2)]
            public uint Next;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 2)]
            public uint Previous;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public char[] Units;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 2)]
            public uint Multiplier;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 2)]
            public uint Divisor;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 2)]
            public uint Base;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 2)]
            public uint Offset;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public char[] Link;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 1)]
            public char pad;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
            public byte[] Name;
    
            public ParameterResponse(uint descriptior, uint value, uint maximum, uint minimum, uint defaultvalue, uint next, uint previous,
                char[] units, uint multiplier, uint divisor, uint baseValue, uint offset, char[] link, char padValue, byte[] name)
            {
                Descriptor = descriptior;
                Value = value;
                Maximum= maximum;
                Minimum= minimum;
                Default = defaultvalue;
                Next= next; Previous= previous;
                Units = units;
                Multiplier = multiplier;
                Divisor = divisor;
                Base = baseValue; Offset = offset;
                Link = link;
                pad = padValue;
                Name = name;
    }
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something in this, because when I try to convert my byteArray to this struct, but the struct is not exactly taking the appropriate sizeconst defined, any inputs would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

`uint16_t` should map to `ushort`, `char` should map to `byte` or `sbyte`, The `Name` field need a `SizeConst` attribute, Using the default pack size.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ParameterResponse
{
    public uint Descriptor;
    public uint Value;
    public uint Minimum;
    public uint Maximum;
    public uint Default;
    public ushort Next;
    public ushort Previous;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public byte[] Units;
    public ushort Multiplier;
    public ushort Divisor;
    public ushort Base;
    public ushort Offset;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public byte[] Link;
    public byte pad;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    public byte[] Name;
}
```

Comment: This is working, but I had a query on this, sometimes I'm getting the Value property as Integer or Float, then in that case what should be type here in the struct

Comment: int/uint/float are OK, just need 4 bytes in the struct.

Comment: but is it possible to declare a type which can support both int and float?, otherwise I'll have to create two different structs to accommodate those data types

Comment: How do you define the struct in C?

Comment: what I've shown in this example

Comment: I mean the type is uint32_t currently, if you know how to pass a float number to it, you can also do the opposite in C# with a uint or int field.

Comment: if i declare uint, then i'm not able to use the same property when i have a response in float, and if i use it as float instead of uint then i'm not able to get the integer value from the response, since now the response is returning int instead of a float, i hope i'm making sense